# Czech alphabet in Ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I have a problem with latest ckeditor. It doesn't display letters from czech alphabet correctly. Instead of letters ě č ř I get question mark. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: I tried all of them and have the same problem. Database and page itself are set to charset windows-1250.

Comment: Use UTF-8 as recommended in [CKEditor Best Practices](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_best_practices-section-use-utf-8).